# Change output format into SQLplus using Crontab

Tags: linux, oracle, save, cron, sqlplus

I'm using **crontab**  to run SQL script. Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/xxx/oracle/client
date=$(date +%d.%m.%y-%T)
echo "select col1, col2 from table1;" |/opt/xxx/oracle/client/bin/sqlplus "abc/abc@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=111.0.0.1)(Port=9999))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sidX)))" > /usr/users/tuser/temp/file.$date.txt
```

Format of the file contains a lof o unnecessary data like:

[image]

How to export just result of query with column headers? (desirable is csv format)

Comment: That's nothing to do with cron per se. You can do the same thing from the command line first. Is there a reason you want the SQL in the crontab itself, rather than in a script you execute from SQL\*Plus?

Comment: You can use `-S`ilent command after `sqlplus` as `sqplus -s user/password`.

Comment: I have reason - the script will be executed at a time

Comment: @ JSapkota: I run with -s, can be data into column somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include SQL*Plus `set` commands in your echoed string, but will also need to embed new lines; switching from echo to printf might make that simpler/cleaer.

You can then concatenate your columns with a comma to get CSV output:

```
printf "set pages 0 lines 200 trimout on tab off feedback off\nselect col1||','||col2 from table1;exit" |  /opt/....
```

I've also increased the line size based on your comment. [You can read more about the settings available](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG060), and [formatting in general](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm).

If your columns include strings that might contain commas, you can enclose their values in double-quotes, which would avoid them being misinterpreted as extra columns by Excel or other tools.

If you want CSV headers as well you can have a dummy query to get them, or use the prompt command to add the fixed text:

```
printf "set pages 0 lines 200 trimout on tab off feedback off\nprompt COL1,COL2\nselect col1||','||col2 from table1;exit" |  /opt/....
```

And you can use the `-s` flag to make SQL*Plus suppress its banners:

```
... exit" | /opt/xxx/oracle/client/bin/sqlplus -s "abc/abc@..."
```

Incidentally, if you can switch from using SID to service name, you could use shorted 'easy connect' syntax instead of the full TNS connect descriptor.

Quick demo with a simple query; if I do this from the command line (split onto two lines just to prevent scrolling):

```
printf "set pages 0 feedback off\nprompt Col1,Col2\nselect dummy||','||dummy from dual;" |\
  /path/to/sqlplus -s myuser/mypass@//myhost:myport/myservicename
```

the entire output I get is:

```
Col1,Col2
X,X
```

I would seriously consider putting at least the SQL commands into a .sql script file and executing that from SQL*Plus; and probably putting the entire command (call to `sqlplus` that executes the script) into a shell script - and you can then just call the shell script from cron.

Comment: it's almost perfect, but I don't know why split one row fro 2 rows? ( I have 12 col)

Comment: @4est - you probably just need to increase the linesize; I added `lines 200`, adjust that number to match how long a single row of output might ever be. Going too high doesn't really hurt for this.